# How can I enable autocompletion in psql in more cases?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm a newbie for RDBMS.

Postgres helps me with auto-completion but it doesn't work for `FROM`, `WHERE`, and `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` clause.

Of course, it is already connected to the database. There are also the schema and table to query.

For example, all keywords following the `SELECT` will not be auto-completed, when I try to enter the following query;

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT district FROM city WHERE countrycode = 'JPN';
```

However, there is no error after I finished typing manually and running. Postgres returns the result normally.

Nonetheless, it works in other clauses such as `CREATE` and `ALTER`.

How can I auto-complete these?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords between `SELECT` and `FROM` ("distinct" and "district" in your example) cannot be auto-completed because the parser does not know what columns, keywords, function names, etc. you are referring to.  If you type `SELECT DI` and press `Tab`, the parser will not know whether you are trying to complete the `DISTINCT` keyword or the `DISTRICT` column name (bear in mind that in Postgres, words are interpreted in case-insensitive fashion, unless double-quotes `"` are used).  After the `FROM` keyword, the parser knows that you are likely going to type in a table name, so it is able to support tab-completion.

Disclosure: I am an [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://enterprisedb.com) employee

Answer (score 1):

richyen's answer is correct as far as column names are concerned.

However, PostgreSQL could certainly offer auto-completion for `DISTINCT`. `DISTINCT` is a reserved keyword in SQL and cannot be used as a column names unless you quote it with double quotes.

The reason why there is no auto-completion for `DISTINCT` is that nobody has implemented it yet.

Comment: So that means that nobody has also implemented it for `FROM` and `WHERE`? These should also be reserved keywords but cannot be auto-completed regardless of the presence of `DISTINCT`. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Perhaps. It is not so useful to guess `FROM` and `WHERE`: it could be an alias instead, like in `SELECT x frob FROM y whence WHERE ...`. Besides those are only four-letter words, so the savings would be small.

Comment: Come to think of it, it may be less useful to implement. However, auto-completion is comfortable. Thank you.